# Python cannot import name if placed in module

Tags: python, import

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to do relative imports in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72852/how-to-do-relative-imports-in-python)

I'm experiencing something that seems very random to me.

I have a folder structure much like this:

```
dir A
    __init__.py is empty
    a.py imports stuff and b.py
dir B
    __init__.py is empty
    b.py imports NOTHING
```

a.py raises an error (cannot import name b). This only happens while b is part of module B.
If I move it outside the directory, the import error does NOT occur.

Any help would be appreciated. I must be overlooking something.

Comment: Could you show the *actual* code being executed?

Comment: B was actually called `utils` and I think that's the real issue here. utils is probably a python dist module and those take precedence. I've renamed the module to `util` which seems to have solved the problem. The weird thing is, that I had other files in the module and imported those without problems.

Comment: This was my problem from messing with someone else's code.. what an obscure issue

Answer (score 4):

Did you try the [relative import](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#intra-package-references)

```
from ..B import b
```

?

---

EDIT: This does not apply if it doesn't matter where package `B` lives.

But you don't describe what exactly you do. As you may know or not, there are several import forms:

```
import module
import package # imports package.__init__ under the name package
import package.module
from package import module
import package
from module import component
from package.module import component
```

As you only write

> a.py imports stuff and b.py

I don't know what exactly happens: if you try to

```
import b
```

that fails because `b` lives in the package `B`. So you need one of

```
from B import b
import B.b
```

Your comment above mentions a name clash. Which of two equally named packages and modules have priority depends on in which directory you are: `'.'` is normally at the very start of `sys.path`, so if you are directly under your `utils` directory you might have a different experience than otherwise.

Comment: I don't see the point of the downvote... please explain.

Comment: It was already suggested that my question is a duplicate of a 'relative import' question. It is now CLOSED as a duplicate. 
But it's not. Since I'm not trying to accomplish a relative import but an absolute one, and I wanted to know why THAT didn't work.

But thank you for taking a shot ;-)

Comment: @A.J.Rouvoet But it sounded like a "relative" problem, and obviously not only to me. Maybe it is a problem of wording in the question.

Comment: Yes I agree with you; I obviously wasn't clear enough. I undid the downvote in accordance.